# SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: record_overflow

Tags: java, ssl

I am receiving the following error. Not sure what is causing this and how to fix this.
  This is happening on the server side which is using Netscalar for Load Balancing.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: record_overflow
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: record_overflow
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:653)
```

Tried, openssl s_client -connect HOST:443

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=test.test.com/OU=management:idms.group.822007/O=Test Inc./ST=California/C=US
   i:/CN=Test Corporate Server CA 1/OU=Certification Authority/O=Test Inc./C=US
 1 s:/CN=Test Corporate Server CA 1/OU=Certification Authority/O=Test Inc./C=US
   i:/CN=Test Corporate Root CA/OU=Certification Authority/O=Test Inc./C=US
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\j+pGT/ZYsOqhHHIngas0nm+IWzZgyCp
vDBgPmuVMBCvRv2N02fBXcAahzq3xJ247EhgcB7y2Ub2hFeHx2dFdVmzFTXLkTQB
R/FSBFxpiDueL5ovp8rK5S65rx37yPKix9xUm8FjQeDvzS8+au+lOg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=test.test.com/OU=management:idms.group.822007/O=Test Inc./ST=California/C=US
issuer=/CN=Test Corporate Server CA 1/OU=Certification Authority/O=Test Inc./C=US
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/CN=Test Corporate Root CA/OU=Certification Authority/O=Test Inc./C=US
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, ECDSA sign, DSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:ECDS:RSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+MD5
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:ECDS:RSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
---
SSL handshake has read 2918 bytes and written 330 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 5B211E74689750F234F57C34ED7FE61FCE21CED8EF2E0C8DD7A20B71AE5D6140
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 1136D67890BCFC70B50CB0D20A96F62A90DDBF59BB4A102FDC3EBF4844C3482DACC31EB37EC92466FBA5927640A17A26
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1547074698
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Comment: Did JDK 13 solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting my answer :-)

Answer (score 21):

If you're on Java 11 or 12, then the reason is probably [a TLSv1.3 bug in the JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221253).

The workaround is to disable TLSv1.3:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

You can also [try the latest JDK 13 early access](https://jdk.java.net/13/) to see whether the issue has been solved.

**Update**
Like Long Nguyen said, this is fixed in:

- JDK 13 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221253)
- JDK 11.0.5 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225714)

Comment: Should be marked as accepted answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Fixed in:**

- JDK 13 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221253)
- JDK 11.0.5 (Release Oct 2019, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225714)

There is no patch for JDK 12

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the string of the SQL query is too long. Try to minify your query by reducing indentations or using smaller aliases. As I don't know the maximum length, first replace the query by a fake tiny query to see if you get rid of this error.

If you are using a method like `findAllById(List<String>)`, then split the list and do it in several calls.