# Why SOAP-UI has SSL handshake issues in version 5.6.0 but version 5.5.0 works perfectly fine?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soapui

Recently we secured our servers with SSL v1.2. We have a SOAP web-service and many endpoints are exposed on it. The endpoints were used to be called/tested with SOAP-UI 5.6.0 with no issues when SSL was not enabled, but now when we call it throws:

```
ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: record_overflow
```

The only workaround we came across was downloading SOAP-UI 5.5.0 and using it since it has no issues calling SSL-enabled web-services.

I also checked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094256/soap-ui-ssl-error-errorjavax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protoc) but unfortunately there is no solid answer on it.

Any idea about the reason is highly appreciated.

Comment: SoapUI upgraded the version of Apache HttpComponents used though I couldn't find which version it was upgraded to.  You didn't say what SSL protocols your endpoint supports but this answer has a reasonable solution even if you're not using Java 11 or 12. I would go further and limit the protocols to TLS v1.1 and v1.2 (i.e. don't support SSLv3 because it's not secure). https://stackoverflow.com/a/56211107/185034

Comment: _Exactly_ what versions of Java? [There was a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221253) reported fixed in 11.0.5 and 8u261. @Paul: avoiding 1.3 may help, but 8 only has 1.3 in 8u261 and it is reported fixed. Although you don't want SSLv3, no action or even care is needed: all Oracle and OpenJDK releases since 2014 have SSLv3 disabled in JSSE and the API (alone) can't reenable it. TLS1.0 could be more of an issue; some standards (like PCI DSS) forbid it, but JSSE doesn't as of now.

Comment: Thanks @Paul and dave_thompson_085

It was my bad, the protocol was v1.3 and I will change the protocol and update the ticket.